# Analyzing behavioral change: Comparing 2 measured weight curves to a model curve

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I'm currently in the process of analyzing experimental data and would like to hear your opinion on the method I would like to use to test my hypothesis.

I had an experimental setup where I recorded the weight of a subject's lunch plate over the course of their meal in 2 conditions on sequential days:

1. Subjects ate their lunch as they would normally do (control ...?)
2. Subjects were instructed to follow eating commands given by an app, designed to influence their eating behavior.

The commands given by the app were based on a curve model that was designed to shape a participant's cumulative intake curve to be quadratic.

My hypothesis is that the recorded intake curve on day 2 is closer to the model curve than the curve recorded on day 1.
In other words: Using the app significantly influences eating behavior, to approach our model curve.

A sample dataset for one participant could look like this when plotted:

[image]

My approach to test this hypothesis is to compute the root of the squared difference between each of the 2 recorded curves and the model curve for each participant. ($n = 420$ for all curves)

$d_{vpID_{Tag1}} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^{n}{(model(x_i) - recorded_{Tag1}(x_i))^2}}$

$d_{vpID_{Tag2}} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^{n}{(model(x_i) - recorded_{Tag2}(x_i))^2}}$

Which leaves me with a data table:
[image]

Now formulating my hypothesis like this:

$H_0 : d_{Tag1} \le d_{Tag2}$

$H_1 : d_{Tag1} \gt d_{Tag2}$

I should be able to test it using a one-way within-subjects (repeated measures) ANOVA, right?

Is this a valid approach in your opinion? Am I missing something or making invalid assumptions? Is the root of the squared difference between measured and model data an adequate measure of similarity in this case?